# Weird output from TCD1304

Tags: ccd, rp2040

I'm working on a project where I need to interact Arduino Nano RP2040 with TCD1304 linear CCD. I managed to solve the signal generating problem and analog reading speed problem with PIO and DMA.

First, I build the schematic from the datasheet [TCD1304AP](http://www.spectronicdevices.com/pdf/TCD1304AP.pdf) [TCD1304DG](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TCD1304DG_Web_Datasheet_en_20190108.pdf?did=13709&prodName=TCD1304DG) using a breadboard
[image: schematic]

But, when I read the signals with oscilloscope, the output seems like switching between two levels and having a noise during switching.
[Video](https://youtu.be/885gFF_lhqM)

Then I accidentally removed the power supply, and itseems that it's showing something when I block the light.
[Video](https://youtu.be/IYcs_81fY5g)

Here's what I think may cause this problem:

1. I didn't use a 10 uF/25 V capacitor because I don't have one now, so I used 10 uF/16 V instead.
2. The ICG doesn't actually be pulled down right after master is high.

[image: ICG not match]

Can someone help me?

**edit: sorry for the typo. Added datasheet for TCD1304AP and TCD1304DG, the chip I'm using is TCD1304DG. The reason why I'm linking TCD1304AP datasheet is that it informed the resistance of the 3 resistors in the drive circuit**

Comment: DMA on a breadboard? That may introduce far too much parasitic capacitance, especially at DMA speeds.  Design a PCB (include extra pads for more capacitors, different resistors, etc.)

Comment: Your first video seems to contain some valid data periods, the second has such a bad configured trigger, that it is hard to say something useful. A falling edge AC trigger on the output signal OS would be helpful.